# Error 401 in JavaScript Dropbox SDK

Tags: javascript, authentication, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to use the Dropbox SDK for Javascript, so I tried a Hello World! to familiarize myself, but I'm getting an error 401 for failed authentication.

[image: Printscreen of the error I am getting]

When I close the pop-up, I click on the button and it redirects me to the authorization page, but after I click on "Allow", it'll show a "Corrupted Content Error" page.

Here's my code, which I really got from a tutorial page in order to test it out:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/dropbox-datastores-1.0-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <button id="writeButton">Click to create <code>hello.txt</code> in Dropbox.</button>
    </center>`

    <script>
        var client = new Dropbox.Client({
            key: KEY// //APP KEY
            secret: "<REDACTED>"//"<REDACTED>"          //APP SECRET
        });

        function doHelloWorld() {
            client.writeFile('hello.txt', 'Hello, World!', function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    alert('Error: ' + error);
                } else {
                    alert('File written successfully!');
                }
            });
        }

        // Try to complete OAuth flow.
        client.authenticate({ interactive: false }, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                alert('Error: ' + error);
            } else {
                doHelloWorld();
            }
        });

        document.getElementById('writeButton').onclick = function () {
            client.authenticate(function (error, client) {
                if (error) {
                    alert('Error: ' + error);
                } else {
                    doHelloWorld();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

It looks like the code I posted on the Dropbox dev blog doesn't work (now?). You need to manually check whether the client is authenticated, since the callback from `client.authenticate` is called no matter what.

I'll update the blog post. The fixed code should look like this:

```
// Try to complete OAuth flow.
client.authenticate({ interactive: false }, function (error) {
    if (error) {
        alert('Error: ' + error);
    } else if (client.isAuthenticated()) { // <-- this line changed
        doHelloWorld();
    }
});
```

---

**Original (wrong) answer**

At first glance, the only difference I can spot between your code and mine (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/71/writing-a-file-with-the-dropbox-javascript-sdk) is that you're specifying an app secret (when you shouldn't be).

If you remove that line, does your app work?

(BTW, I redacted the app secrets you posted, but they're still visible in the edit history. I'd recommend deleting those apps and creating new ones.)

Comment: Will do that, thanks, don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: And I removed the secret, but it's still not working

Comment: It looks like the code in that sample is no longer working... I'm investigating what changed in the library. I'll reply back when I have it figured out!

Comment: That got rid of the 401 error, though I'm still not getting redirected to the webpage after authorization.

Comment: Where are you running the app? It needs to be on a web server, since redirects will work for HTTP (on localhost) and HTTPS but not `file://` URLs.